# rails 4 route matching order

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

```
# Individual Page
get '/manage/:type', to: 'manage#profile', as: :profile

# Detail Page
get '/manage/:id', to: 'manage#detail', as: :detail
```

In the code above, even if I create a url such as

```
<%= link_to "Detail Page", detail_url(:id => 2) %>
```

it still goes to profile action of the manage controller (even though it asks for **type** and not **id**).

Is this expected behavior in rails 4.1, or am I doing something wrong?

I thought that, if I have a named route, I can pass the appropriate parameters (:id => 2), and have it skip past the first route, simply because it does not match the route name.

**Of course, things work as intended, if I reverse the order, and put "Detail" route before the profile route.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about the pattern matching.

Add some constant text to disambiguate them -- *e.g.*,

```
get 'manage/profile/:type', to: 'manage#profile', as :profile

get 'manage/detail/:id', to: 'manage#detail', as :detail
```